# Is there a way to bypass requirement to include boost sockets header before winsock.h?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, boost

I try to use Boost's sockets library. The program is big and complex. It uses libcurl for HTTP requests and Boost sockets for custom protocol based on TCP/IP. Because code base is very big, it is annoying to review each file where I include boost directly or indirectly and make sure that I never include them before `curl.h` or `windows.h` that may include `WinSock.h`.
Are there any way to use Boost sockets without requirement to include it before `WinSock.h`? `libcurl` allows you to include `WinSock.h` before it, so why `Boost` has this strange requirement?

Comment: If your sources include the infamous `StdAfx.hpp` you can include everything there and forget about the issue. Maybe not the finest solution, but it should work.

Comment: What about one file that includes everything in the correct order and allow only include of that?

Comment: I don't use stdafx.h. I update existing software that uses libcurl, and because for libcurl it is not important where you include WinSock.h, I never cared in my code about specific order of include files. It looks like there are not easy solution.

Comment: BTW, if you already use Boost.Asio, wouldn't it be simpler to use HTTP from cpp-netlib, which is based on Asio.